# How do I delete my identity users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to delete duplicate but clever users who has figured out that they can create an account using more than one email. My application has a UserLog a way for me to track my users through the site for risk management purposes. Here is my UserLog class:

```
public class UserLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
}
```

In my `ManageUsers` controller I know I need to delete the logs created by the user before I delete the user because of the `FK_constraint` I created in the class. Finally I attempt to delete the user. Here is what I tried:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string UserName)
{
    var ocustomerId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var oCustomer = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == ocustomerId).ToString();

    //delete user logs
    _context.UserLogs
       .Where(p => p.Customer.Id == oCustomer)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(p => _context.UserLogs.Remove(p));
    _context.SaveChanges();

    //finally delete from aspnetUsers table
    var thisUser =
    _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    _context.Users.Remove(thisUser);
    _context.SaveChanges(); \\it breaks here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

As expected the first portion of the code works as expected deleting the logs created by the user the user. The error occurs on the second `context.SaveChanges()`.

The error generated by the breakpoint is:

> DbUpdateException error occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Whereas, the error generated on the actual error page is as follows:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.UserLogs_dbo.AspNetUsers_Customer_Id". The conflict occurred
>   in database "myDB", table "dbo.UserLogs", column 'Customer_Id'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You delete logs for the currently logged in user:

```
 var ocustomerId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
 var oCustomer = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == ocustomerId).ToString();
```

But later you are trying to delete the user by UserName from the method parameter. I doubt the UserName equals currently loged in user.

First, pass user id to the method. Retrieve the user by this id and then delete the entry

```
     public ActionResult Delete(string UserName)
    {
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var user = userManager.FindByName(UserName);

        _context.UserLogs
           .Where(p => p.Customer.Id == user.Id)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(p => _context.UserLogs.Remove(p));

        _context.SaveChanges(); 
        userManager.Delete(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Btw, do not call SaveChanges twice.

Comment: that worked! in addition, I have already removed the other places in my applications where I was calling `SaveChanges()` twice. Besides being a code smell, can you elaborate why it is bad to do so?

Comment: it is not bad, sometimes you really need to call SaveChanges several times within one function. By calling SaveChanges you commit your cached EF objects from the current Context to the Database. So in your example you had 2 issues. 1. You tried to delete logs from the database just after selecting them into the context (first savechanges call), and then you tried to delete a wrong user. Call savechanges every timeyou finish working with the database or you really need your data to be saved before continuing the method.